# Jquery conflict with flexslider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, conflict

I want to scroll to a div when I load my page, and I can do it using Jquery with this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function (){
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(".active").offset().top
    }, 2000);
    return false;
});
</script>
```

In the same page I have a slider created using flexslider.

After importing flexslider css and js I done this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function($) {
    $(window).load(function(){
        $('.flexslider').flexslider({
            animation: "slide",
            start: function(slider){
                $('body').removeClass('loading');
            }
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

At this link you can see all the flexslider file: https://github.com/woothemes/FlexSlider

The problem is when the page is loaded, the scroll start correctly, but at a certain point 
seems that while the scrollout is running  the slider is loaded at the same time and this creates problems to the scrollout that does not seem to know where to position the window.

Anyone can help me? I'm getting mad with this, I tried to find an answer on the net but I have not met anyone with my problem.

Thank you.

Comment: why don't you try to merge both code in one $(document).ready() ? this way they are called at same point and might solve your problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript / jQuery loading (conflict)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12111141/javascript-jquery-loading-conflict)

Comment: @SumitGupta If I do in that way I still got the same results.

Comment: @atallon yes, but how to solve it?

Comment: Well, can you try to put all code in ready(), in order that just call Flexislider and than at last put your body scroll code. and do not put return false. I hope that might solve it.